# I'm writing a TSQL procedure and have a query that extracts data . However it's returning the divide by zero error exception

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, isnull

Divide by zero error exception from the below code though I have used `ISNULL` in my code. Any suggestions on how to fix this.

```
SELECT 
    dd.detail_id DETAIL_ID, dd.period_id PERIOD_ID, noff.FGA_ID FGA_ID,
    noff.fulfillment_center FULFILLMENT_CENTER, noff.DEMAND_TYPE DEMAND_TYPE,
    noff.LEGACY_SSC LEGACY_SSC,
    noff.net_offset_forecast NET_OFFSET_FORECAST,
    noff.forecast_to_be_consumed FORECAST_TO_BE_CONSUMED,
    CASE 
       WHEN ISNULL(dd.DEPOT_WISE_FORECAST, 0) = 0 
          THEN 0 
          ELSE (noff.net_offset_forecast * dd.detail_depot_wise_forecast) / ISNULL((dd.agg_depot_wise_forecast), 0))
    END detail_forecast_consumption,
    CASE 
       WHEN ISNULL(dd.DEPOT_WISE_FORECAST, 0) = 0 
          THEN 0 
          ELSE (noff.FORECAST_TO_BE_CONSUMED * dd.detail_depot_wise_forecast) / ISNULL((dd.agg_depot_wise_forecast), 0))
    END detail_forecast_sales
INTO 
    aggregate_to_detail_forecast_consumption                          
FROM 
    net_offset_forecast noff 
JOIN
    disaggregate_data dd ON noff.fga_id = dd.snop_item  
                         AND noff.fulfillment_center = dd.fulfillment_center 

SELECT 
    dd.detail_id DETAIL_ID, dd.period_id PERIOD_ID, noff.FGA_ID FGA_ID,
    noff.fulfillment_center FULFILLMENT_CENTER,
    noff.DEMAND_TYPE DEMAND_TYPE, noff.LEGACY_SSC LEGACY_SSC,
    noff.net_offset_forecast NET_OFFSET_FORECAST,
    noff.forecast_to_be_consumed FORECAST_TO_BE_CONSUMED,
    CASE 
       WHEN ISNULL(dd.DEPOT_WISE_FORECAST, 0) = 0
          THEN 0 
          ELSE (noff.net_offset_forecast * dd.detail_depot_wise_forecast) / ISNULL((dd.agg_depot_wise_forecast), 0))
    END detail_forecast_consumption,
    CASE 
       WHEN ISNULL(dd.DEPOT_WISE_FORECAST, 0) = 0 
          THEN 0 
          ELSE (noff.FORECAST_TO_BE_CONSUMED * dd.detail_depot_wise_forecast) / ISNULL((dd.agg_depot_wise_forecast), 0))
    END detail_forecast_sales
INTO 
    aggregate_to_detail_forecast_consumption                          
FROM 
    net_offset_forecast noff 
JOIN
    disaggregate_data dd ON noff.fga_id = dd.snop_item  
                         AND noff.fulfillment_center = dd.fulfillment_center
```

There should be No divide by zero exception with the above code

Comment: At first glance it seems that whenever something is NULL, you use 0. Well, it's not a DivideByNullException, but a DivideByZeroException. Dividing by 0 is not possible.

Comment: Look at these expressions: `ELSE (... * ...) / ISNULL((dd.agg_depot_wise_forecast), 0))` - what if `dd.agg_depot_wise_forecast` is in fact `NULL` ?? Then you replace that `NULL` with a `0` and divide by it !! That's your "divide by zero" exception right there - **several times** in your SQL !

Answer (score 2):

You don't want `/ ISNULL(dd.agg_depot_wise_forecast, 0)`.

This will return either `dd.agg_depot_wise_forecast` or `0`, depending on whether the first argument is `NULL`.

You want to use `NULLIF()`:  `/ NULLIF(dd.agg_depot_wise_forecast, 0)`.

This will replace zero values with `NULL`, avoiding the error.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the value and do not attempt top divide when it is NULL. When it is NULL, you are replacing it with 0 and causing a divide by zero error. 
Here is a sample:

```
declare @sample table (id int identity, v1 decimal(10,2), v2 decimal(10,2) null);

insert into @sample (v1, v2) values 
(10,2),
(10,null);

--select *, v1/isnull(v2,0)
--from @sample;

select *, case when v2 is null then 0 else v1/v2 end as MyVal
from @sample;
```

Commented part is how you do it and would error.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly replace your case statement with below corrected case statement.

Changes:
ISNULL((dd.agg_depot_wise_forecast),0) -> ISNULL(NULLIF(dd.agg_depot_wise_forecast,0), 1)

NULLIF() will replace 0 value with NULL value, so ISNULL() will always take 1 from second argument.

```
CASE WHEN ISNULL(dd.DEPOT_WISE_FORECAST, 0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (noff.net_offset_forecast * dd.detail_depot_wise_forecast) / ISNULL(NULLIF(dd.agg_depot_wise_forecast,0), 1)) END detail_forecast_consumption, CASE WHEN ISNULL(dd.DEPOT_WISE_FORECAST, 0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (noff.FORECAST_TO_BE_CONSUMED * dd.detail_depot_wise_forecast) / ISNULL(NULLIF(dd.agg_depot_wise_forecast,0), 1)) END detail_forecast_sales
```